# RandomForestClassifier is throwing error: one field contains comma-separated values

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, random-forest

I am trying to fit a RandomForestClassifier, like this.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(col_trans, rf_classifier)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['4G, 4G LAA, 5G NR', '4G,4G CBRS,5G FIXED'] in column 3 during transform
```

The field named `'technology_type'` contains comma separated values, like this: `4G, 5G, NR`

How can I handle these comma separated values?  I suppose I could eliminate that field, but I really want to include it as an independent variable for X.

Here is all of my code.

```
df_fuze = pd.read_sql("""select * from fuze""", conn_connection)

# copy features to new DF
fuze = df_fuze[['territory',
        'submarket',
        'local_market',
        'technology_type',
        'project_type',
        'modification_type',
        'objective',
        'construction_completed_days']]

fuze.head()

# set dependent variable
y = fuze['construction_completed_days']

# set the independent variables
X = fuze.drop('construction_completed_days', 1)

seed = 50  # so that the result is reproducible
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.333, random_state = seed)


X_train = X_train.fillna('na')
X_test = X_test.fillna('na')

features_to_encode = list(X_train.select_dtypes(include = ['object']).columns) 
# Or alternatively, 
# features_to_encode = X_train.columns[X_train.dtypes==object].tolist()

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
col_trans = make_column_transformer(
                        (OneHotEncoder(),features_to_encode),
                        remainder = "passthrough"
                        )

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(
                      min_samples_leaf=50,
                      n_estimators=150,
                      bootstrap=True,
                      oob_score=True,
                      n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=seed,
                      max_features='auto')

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(col_trans, rf_classifier)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The error occurs after trying to fit the X & y variables.

I am following the example from here.

https://towardsdatascience.com/my-random-forest-classifier-cheat-sheet-in-python-fedb84f8cf4f

Comment: I think there is a row that contains `['4G, 4G LAA, 5G NR', '4G,4G CBRS,5G FIXED']` value in the `technology_type` column. And because it has `,` so it raises the error you see. Normally, it should be separate, it should only have `'4G, 4G LAA, 5G NR'` or `4G,4G CBRS,5G FIXED`.

Comment: I found this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/14851/90996) may help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have this dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'product_code': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                 'technology_type': ['4G, 4G LAA, 5G NR',
                            '4G,4G CBRS,5G FIXED',
                            '4G, 5G, NR',
                            '4G, NR']},
                columns=['product_code', 'technology_type'])
```

Output:

```
product_code    technology_type
1               4G, 4G LAA, 5G NR
2               4G,4G CBRS,5G FIXED
3               4G, 5G, NR
4               4G, NR
```

First, your data should contain one `technology_type` category at a time.

```
cleaned = data.set_index('product_code').technology_type.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
```

Output:

```
product_code   
1             0          4G
              1      4G LAA
              2       5G NR
2             0          4G
              1     4G CBRS
              2    5G FIXED
3             0          4G
              1          5G
              2          NR
4             0          4G
              1          NR
```

Then you can able to apply `get_dummies()` and `merge` back to your data.

```
technology_type_dummies = pd.get_dummies(cleaned).groupby(level=0).sum()
newData = data.merge(technology_type_dummies, left_on='product_code', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
product_code    technology_type     4G LAA  5G  5G NR   NR     4G   4G CBRS    5G FIXED
1               4G, 4G LAA, 5G NR   1       0   1       0      1    0          0
2               4G,4G CBRS,5G FIXED 0       0   0       0      1    1          1
3               4G, 5G, NR          0       1   0       1      1    0          0
4               4G, NR              0       0   0       1      1    0          0
```

Remember to remove white space in the beginning and in the end of the column name just in case.

```
newData.columns = newData.columns.str.strip()
```

Then you can drop the `technology_type` column. The data type of the dummy columns is an integer so it will not exist in `features_to_encode` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this.  Very useful.